# Getting events from specific calendar Google API Python

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I use the quickstart.py code from the Google API to get the events from a calendar. Its the code below, the exact stept are on here https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
import datetime

# Setup the Calendar API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Calendar API
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                  maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                  orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    print(start, event['summary'])
```

This is working fine for me. Now i added another calendar to my account, copied my code into another folder and ran through the steps (google link) again. I put the secound .json into the secound folder and tested it.

Even though it should be able to access both calendars it only retrieves the events from the first calendar. So I wonder how to access the other calendar (preferably only the secound one but i both at once would be helping too).

I did search through the Google documentation which didnt help and every Stackoverflow question i found relies on another programming language (and i fail to append it to python) or the answers contain links to sites that dont exist anymore.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the calendar from which you want to retrieve events passing the correct `calendarId` to [`service.events().list()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.events.html#list). `'primary'` can always be used to get the primary calendar of the user, you can get the information of all the calendars the user has with [`service.calendarList().list()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.calendarList.html#list).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I found the id in the calendar settings and exchanged primary with the id. 
I´ll use your function to get the id later on so it will run automatically.